# The last digit for 3^(2019)

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Which would be the last digit for $3^{2019}$ ?

---

You can

> check last digits for $3^x$ with $x=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and see if something is repeated.

And afterwards

> think about modulus for the exponent number and the pattern found.

Comment: No need to include hints, this is easy enough already for someone who knows maths :-)

Comment: Should I remove the hints? Just new to this Stackexchange site and not sure when and whether should I include hints when knowing the answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Also, I see you edited my question and added LateX format. Is that possible on titles as well?

Comment: Hints are usually added *after* posting the puzzle, as a way to point people in the right direction if nobody gets the answer for a while. I'd say you can remove them. And yes, LaTeX format is also possible in titles, but it makes questions ineligible for the Hot Network Questions list.

Comment: This looks more like a math *problem*, not *puzzle*.

Comment: @trolley813 I disagree. It's easy for those of us who've studied some number theory, sure, but the method of solution would be very interesting and "aha"-ish for someone who hasn't seen it before. I could easily imagine this as an olympiad problem, for example (not IMO but maybe a subnational olympiad). Sometimes we forget that what's second nature to us may be a fascinating innovation for non-mathematicians :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because

> $3^4=81\equiv1 \:(\text{mod}\;10)$,

and

> $2019=(4\times504)+3\equiv3\:(\text{mod}\;4)$,

we have

> $3^{2019}=(3^4)^{504}\times3^3\equiv(1)^{504}\times3^3=27\equiv7\:(\text{mod}\;10)$,

so the answer is

> $7$.

Comment: Equally interesting is: "what is the *first* digit of $3^{2019}$?".

Answer (score 1):

As we know,

> Powers of 3 are numbers ending in $\{1,3,9,7\}$ sequentially.

As

> $MOD(2019,4)=3$

So we know that

> The last digit for $3^{2019}$ will be the forth in the sequence stated in the beginning. As if result was 0 it would have been the first element.

So the result is that the last digit for $3^{2019}$ is:

> $7$

Comment: Well, the first spoilerblock ("As we know ...") is really the key point. Rather than assuming such a pattern (even though I do know it's always going to be like that), in my answer I gave an argument which anyone could follow even knowing nothing about modular arithmetic, as long as they know what $\equiv\:(\text{mod}\;n)$ actually means.

Comment: The list in the first spoilerblock isn’t in the correct order, although it’s not specified if it’s 0-indexed or 1-indexed

Comment: @CharlieHarding, you are right. Just corrected the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The list of last digits:

$3$

$9$ ($3×3$)

$7$ ($3×3×3$)

$1$ ($3×3×3×3$)

And then the cycle repeats again.
So, 3 to the 2019 th power is same as $3^3$(There is a cycle of 4).
Which gives 27,which have a last digit of 7.