# First digit of 3^2020

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

Inspired by
[The last digit for 3^(2019)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96867/the-last-digit-for-32019)

Can you find the **first** digit of 3<sup>2020</sup> without a computer?

Comment: @StewieGriffin but does that rule out a calculator? I don't know $\log_{10}3$ up to enough decimal places ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I would prefer an answer without a calculator. But if one is not found then I will accept your answer, which is pretty cool too.

Comment: The hard thing is to post the answer here without using a computer.

Comment: Can I choose the base of my answer? If it has to be 10, [can it still be three](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166869/331040)? My answer is `1`.

Comment: @BruceWayne no problem, I think you're right. Note that most of the visits here come from the Hot Network Questions, and there you can't see whether a question has an accepted answer or not. But the Puzzling (and/or Math) users might indeed not try to answer a question with an already accepted answer.

Comment: Technically anything can be done without a computer. It just takes time.

Comment: I believe that there will be a pattern somewhere because I've calculated 33 numbers and there seems to be a pattern

Comment: @UnidentifiedX that is very interesting indeed! Can you please post the pattern you found.

Comment: @Dmitry Kamenetsky $3 9 2 8 2 7 2 6 1 5 1 5 1 4 1 4 1 3 1 3 1$ Then it _seems_ to repeat $3 9 2 8 2 7 2 6 2 6 1 5...$ But then a few numbers were changed

Comment: Is a [table of logarithms](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/logtable/logtable.html) allowed?

Comment: @UnidentifiedX there is no pattern. There's a mathematical proof for that. Observe that $a\cdot 10^k < 3^n < (a+1)\cdot 10^k$ means that the first digit is $a$, taking $\log=\log_{10}$ we see that $\log a + k < n \log 3 < log(a+1) + k$. Now consider the fraction part, we see that the first digit is $a$ iff $\{ n \log3\} \in (\log a, \log(a+1))$. However $\log 3$ is an irrational number and therefore $\{n\cdot \log 3\}$ uniformly distributing in $(0,1)$. (All first digits appear, randomly with different distribution. The probability that $a$ appears is $\log(a+1)-\log(a)$).

Comment: @UnidentifiedX To add to my previous comment (it was too long). It's not trivial that $\{n\cdot \log 3\}$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ (aka equidistributed sequence). Here's a reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski if we can choose the base, then I will take base two. The first digit is  `1`.

Comment: @Džuris I will take base three then, much more impressive. The first digit is also `1`.

Comment: @DidierL yeah, but that was already taken by Kamil above :( So I had to claim the trivial one.

Comment: Why would you not choose base $3486784401$? The first digit there is also 1.

Comment: @FlorianF That's easy if (like me) you are ancient enough to have used 4-figure log tables back in high school. (Slide rules didn't have 4 figure precision and electronic calculators hadn't been invented yet). You quickly learned a few common values like log 2 = 0.3010 and log 3 = 0.4771 simply by repetition. (And there was one nerd in the class who memorised the complete 4-figure table, to save time!!)

Comment: @Glorfindel Sorry to go offtopic, but I am one of those that came from the Hot Network Questions. Is there a reason puzzling is more often in HNQ?

Comment: @PascalVKooten Puzzling has 1) relatively high quality content 2) many active (up)voters and 3) a theme which is apparently appealing to the average Stack Exchange audience (which mostly consists of programmers).

Comment: @PascalVKooten surely they are drawn to my great puzzles ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure first digit of $3^n$ forms a repititive pattern.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think it's a

> 6

Explanation:

> $$3^{2020} = 10^{\log_{10}(3^{2020})} = 10^{2020 \log_{10}3}$$

According to my calculator (this answer was posted before the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag was added),

> $$2020 \log_{10}3 = 963.784934533718123$$
>  and
>  $$10^{963.784934533718123} = 10^{963} \times 10^{0.784934533718123} = 10^{963} \times 6.094450215462886$$
>  Multiplying by $10^{963}$ doesn't influence the first digit, only the 'length', so the answer is 6.

If we're not allowed to use computers, I would

> still use the same trick. $\log_{10}3$ is common enough to be listed in a [logarithm table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms), I must have one in my library. Multiplying by 2020 is doable by hand, and it's easy to verify with the logarithm table that the fractional part (0.785) lies between $\log_{10}6$ and $\log_{10}7$, so the first digit must be a 6.

The same trick is used to solve similar questions on our sister site Mathematics: [Finding the first digit of $2015^{2015}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136514/228959) and [What's the first digit of 2410^2410?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605090/228959)

Comment: The result is correct

Comment: It should be possible to find $\log_{10} 3$ to sufficient precision without a table by expanding $\log_{10}$ around $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE wouldn't that shift the problem to finding $\sqrt{10}$ with sufficient precision (which is admittedly easier, but still)? Feel free to write your own answer, by the way; it's quite common on Stack Exchange (and especially on Puzzling) to base answers off one another.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Finding sqrt with arbitrary precision is just binary search and square (multiply).

Comment: @Glorfindel There are plenty of techniques for finding roots by hand.  You could probably find one for log too; but for square roots it's fairly trivial and a really well studied problem.

Answer (score 37):

This is one way to do it with the help of binary numbers. It is called exponentiation by squaring.

EDIT
Thanks to the few comments that pointed out the mistakes in my calculations. I was very lucky to get the right answer. While revising, I also noticed a mathematical mistake that explains why I need 4 digits to get the right answer. I'll leave the old answer, then explain why it didn't work. And finally, I'll add a new answer that works.

---

**First answer (wrong one)**

First, $2020$ is $11111100100$ in binary. So
$$3^{2020}=3^{1024}3^{512}3^{256}3^{128}3^{64}3^{32}3^{4}$$
Now we find $3^{2^n}$, by squaring the previous one.
$$\begin{array}n&3^{2^n}&\text{value}\\0&3^1&3\\1&3^2&9\\2&3^4&81\\3&3^8&6561\end{array}$$
Starting from $3^8$ the values are too big, we keep only the first three digits. *By doing so, we have a relative error of less than one in a thousand. We have about 20 multiplications to do, so the relative error of the answer will be less than 2%.*
$$\begin{array}n&3^{2^n}&\text{first 3 digits rounded}\\0&3^1&3\\1&3^2&9\\2&3^4&81\\3&3^8&656\\4&3^{16}&430\\5&3^{32}&185\\6&3^{64}&342\\7&3^{128}&117\\8&3^{256}&137\\9&3^{512}&188\\10&3^{1024}&353\end{array}$$
To find the final value, we multiply the one we need
\begin{align}3^{2020}&=3^{1024}3^{512}3^{256}3^{128}3^{64}3^{32}3^{4}\\3^{2020}&=(353)(188)(137)(117)(342)(185)(81)\\3^{2020}&=545\ldots\end{align}
The first digit of $3^{2020}$ is $5$ (wrong).

---

**Why it didn't work**

My mistake is when I check the relative error. The relative error on $3^8$ is around 0.1%. Then, the error **doubled** every time I squared. Since I squared 7 times, the relative error of $3^{1024}$ is around 12.8%, which is way too high. We need a fourth digit to find the answer.

---

**New version**

First, $2020$ is $11111100100$ in binary. So
$$3^{2020}=3^{1024}3^{512}3^{256}3^{128}3^{64}3^{32}3^{4}$$
Now we find $3^{2^n}$, by squaring the previous one.

Now if we keep 4 digits for every number, we have
$$\begin{array}n&3^{2^n}&\text{first 4 digits rounded}\\0&3^1&3\\1&3^2&9\\2&3^4&81\\3&3^8&6561\\4&3^{16}&4305\\5&3^{32}&1853\\6&3^{64}&3434\\7&3^{128}&1179\\8&3^{256}&1390\\9&3^{512}&1932\\10&3^{1024}&3733\end{array}$$
To find the final value, we multiply the one we need
\begin{align}3^{2020}&=3^{1024}3^{512}3^{256}3^{128}3^{64}3^{32}3^{4}\\3^{2020}&=(3733)(1932)(1390)(1179)(3434)(1853)(81)\\3^{2020}&=60919\ldots\end{align}
The first digit of $3^{2020}$ is $6$.

---

**Conclusion**

This method works, but could need a lot of work. I did it by hand (and double checked with a spreadsheet) before posting, since there is a [no-computer](/questions/tagged/no-computer) tag.

Since the real value of $3^{2020}$ is $6.0945\times10^{963}$, we need a relative error below 1% to find the right answer. We may need to verify our answer by keeping 5 digits.

**EDIT 2** Suggestion from @DidierL.

As suggested in the comments, we could use a division to reduce the multiplications by one.
$$3^{2020}=\frac{3^{2048}}{3^{16}3^83^4}$$
$3^{2048}$ start with $13935$, with the same logic as before. And
$$3^{16}3^83^4=(4305)(6561)(81)=2288$$
Keeping only the first four digits.
Finally
$$13935\div2288=60904\ldots$$
Once again, I tried it by hand (double check with calculator) before posting.

Comment: This technique is also called [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: @2012rcampion thank's, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel you are right. I'll post an updated answer soon.

Comment: Also, squaring 118... would give 137...ish, not 103...

Comment: It turns out the rounding error (and maybe the math error) here is TERRIBLE.  3^1024 starts with 373, not 106.  [used computer].  I suggest keeping a few more digits.  I suspect you lost a power of 10 in the rounding.

Comment: @DavidG. Yes the rounding error are terrible, I need 4 digits to have the right solution. I didn't backcheck before I posted. I'll do a revised version.

Comment: This is a nice answer that can potentially be done without a calculator. Although it seems to be quite error prone.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I agree with you. As for any pen and paper question, one has to be careful. This one have an awful lot of small computation to do and it is error prone. But it is doable.

Comment: @AlainRemillard yep definitely doable if you are careful and have lots of time. Well done on the great answer.

Comment: You could trade 3 multiplications for a division by computing 3^2048 / 3^(16+8+4). As you are only interested in the first digit, you don't even need to compute the full division.

Comment: @DidierL, thank's, I have added it to the answer.

Comment: This inspired me to propose a question on CodeGolf for anyone interested - Currently in the sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18841/62289

Comment: @simonalexander2005 have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expressions. I'm not sure if it works on all the site of the SE Network. Basically, you place your math between dollar signs. E.g. `$a^b$` become $a^b$.

Comment: Still shorter is $3^{2048} \div 3^{32} \times 3^4$.  If you compute with 4 digits precision you get 6094.

Comment: ...and if anyone's interested, the final question on codegolf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204292/the-first-digit-of-a-to-the-power-of-b-approximately

Answer (score 18):

With no computers and a calculator used only to check some easy arithmetic:

First of all, calculate some small powers of $3$ looking for things that might be easy to work with. I notice that $3^{13} = 1594323$ which is close to $1600000$, and powers of $2$ and $10$ are nice. The relative error is about $5000/160000$ or $1/320$.

In particular, $2^{10}$ is approximately a power of $10$. So let's take the fifth power, so we get $$3^{65} \approx 16^5 \cdot 10^{25} \cdot \left(1-\frac 1{320}\right)^5 \approx 2^{20} \cdot 10^{25} \cdot \left(1-\frac 1{64}\right)$$. And we know that $2^{20} = 1048576 \approx 10^6 \cdot (1+0.0486)$, so 
$$3^{65} \approx 10^{31} \cdot 1.033 \approx 10^{31} \cdot \left(1+\frac 1{30}\right)$$. (Why $1.033$? Because $1/64 = 0.015625$; multiplying number near $1 \approx$ adding differences from $1$, and $0.0486-0.0156 = 0.033$.)

That factor of $1+1/30$ is a bit of a nuisance. What can we do with it? Well, it's well known that $(1+1/n)^n$ is roughly $e$ for largeish $n$. So let's take the $30^\text{th}$ power, which conveniently comes close to $2020$: $3^{1950} \approx 10^{930}e$. This is a slight overestimate because $0.033$ is a little smaller than $1/30$ and because $(1+1/n)^n$ is a little smaller than $e$.

We're $70$ short, and we happen to have something pretty good for $65$, so let's multiply by $3^{65}$. $$3^{2015} \approx 10^{961}(1+1/30)e$$ And $3^5$ is a nice small number so let's just throw that in: $$3^{2020} \approx 10^{961} * \left(1+\frac 1{30}\right)e(243) \approx 10^{963}\left(1+\frac 1{30}\right)e(2.43)$$

Finally, just do some arithmetic. $2.72 \times 2.43 \approx 5.44 \times 1.21 \approx 5.44 + 1.09 \approx 6.5$ (because $.2 = 1/5$); the $1+1/30$ factor turns this into about $6.7$.

None of that was super-accurate, but the most estimate-y bit of it is known to be an overestimate and I don't see any way we could be out by more than $+0.3$ or $-0.7$. So the first digit is $6$. (Which indeed it turns out to be, and indeed this was an overestimate; the number actually begins $60944$.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a $6$ due to some mathematical reasons. Consider logs base 10.

$log(3)$ is $0.477121254...$,and this number times $2020$ is $963.7849345...$

We can ignore the first three digits *which are about how many digits the number has*. This leaves a remainder of $0.7849345...$

$log(6)$ is $0.77715...$
and $log(7)$ is $0.84509804...$
This shows that our number lies between them, so the first digit is $6$.

(The answer actually starts with $6094450215$.)