# First digit of 2021^2021

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

Can you find the **first** digit of $2021^{2021}$ without a computer? Good luck!

Comment: Isn't the methodology basically the same as [first digit of 3^2020](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97179/71652)?

Comment: It think the only difference is log(2021) = log (43)+log(47), agreed basically the same.

Comment: [The first Google Images hit on "logarithm table"](http://www.sliderules.info/a-to-z/log-tables.htm) gives the value of log(2.021) just fine.

Comment: Wait, the table gives 2021×log(2.021) ~ 2021×0.3056 = 617.6176, which gives the starting digit of 4, but it's incorrect...

Comment: @Bubbler It seems that you need at least 5 decimals of accuracy because of that 4-digit factor 2021.

Comment: I agree about the closure of this question. I forgot that I already made a similar question.